# How to make TextMeshPro input field adjust its raycast area based on its text?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I'm creating UI for my game. I've already created simple elements like animated buttons and multi-option switches, but I have a problem with input fields.

That's how it looks now.

[image]

---

#### My goal

Raycast receiving area should be same size as text.

Text pivot should be (0.5, 0.5), because the animation changes its scale. It's not nice when long text scales not around the center. Raycast area should not be affected by scale.

---

#### My attempts

[image]

**input-32** has a **Layout Element** with **Flexible Width** set to 1, so it should fill all available space. **Text Area** has a **Horizontal Layout Group** (see picture). Inside there are a spacer with **Flexible Width** set to 1, a placeholder and a text.

It does now work:

[image]

Selection is at wrong place, and text uncontrollably flies to the left sometimes. It seems that input field does not expect elements other than text and placeholder to be here and works as if they were not present.

OK, then put the spacer under **input-32** directly. However, behavior is exactly the same.

I figured out that field breaks when I add a **Content Size Fitter** to text element. But how to control its width, which raycasting depends on? Probably I should not resize the text but override its raycasting, but I don't know how.

---

I have to admit, I don't understand how TextMeshPro input fields work at low level and that's why my attempts are failing. Can you help me or give a hint at least?

Comment: So, out of curiosity, if the input field contains an empty string (`""`) because it has either been blanked by the user or otherwise populated with a string of zero length, how wide should the clickable area be?

Comment: @Draco18s It should have a minimum width, otherwise it'll be unclickable

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few combinations of `ContentSizeFitter` and `HorizontalLayoutGroup` as you did, and it didn't work well. I also tried making a custom size fitter. In the end, I created a simple component that just resizes the text field to match the preferred size of the text each frame. It could be optimised a little, but it works pretty well in my tests. I think taking the resizing out of the UI's layout system fixes the issues with the caret - as the caret is moved within the layout system and the two things fight with each-other.

The only issue I've noticed with this approach is that whitespace at the end of the input doesn't affect the 'preferred size' of the text (not entirely sure why) so the text field doesn't expand to show this.

You should also probably remove the `RectMask2D` component on the "Text Area" game object as leaving this there will cut off half of the caret (and isn't required in your case).

Add this script to your object with the `TMP_InputField` on:

```c#
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ResizeInputToMatchText : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RectTransform m_Rect;
    private RectTransform m_inputFieldRect;

    private RectTransform rectTransform
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Rect == null)
                m_Rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            return m_Rect;
        }
    }

    private RectTransform inputFieldTextRectTransform
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_inputFieldRect == null)
                m_inputFieldRect = GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().textComponent.rectTransform;
            return m_inputFieldRect;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        rectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, LayoutUtility.GetPreferredSize(inputFieldTextRectTransform, 0));
        inputFieldTextRectTransform.localPosition = Vector3.zero; // stops the text scrolling sideways - it doesn't need to
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Ok, i tried that but I guess I have wrong setup of components on objects. My text is center-aligned and when I select it it shakes rapidly. Which setup of components shouuld I have? Btw, thanks for the hint about LayoutUtility.